# Add ruby code in logstash config "output" section

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using logstash to receive JSON content and then write out to log files.
I have the basic configuration going.

However, I like to add some ruby processing logic under "output" section of the configuration file such that I can drop incoming content into different files based on hour of the day they arrive.

Can anyone point me to any example where the "output" section in the configuration file has ruby processing logic?   I am unable to find examples
on how to write such a logic in the "output" section.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only ruby code that can be used is in a ruby filter in the filters section.  Generally that means you need to do all of your logic in the filters section and then do conditional output in the output section.

In the output section, you can use event values that you set in the filter section, so you could figure out where you're going to output something in the filters section and then just pass the filename in the event.

If you are worried about the values showing up on the event, you can use the [@metadata][whatever_here] so that the values don't show up on the event.  See https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-metadata for more details.

You can use `if`/`then`/`else` in the output section to conditionally use different outputs based on some value in the event (or event metadata).  Along with the `%{[@metadata][value]}` syntax, you should be able to construct any output that you need with appropriate values.

Comment: thanks, I am able to get what I want now.  Thanks for your tips